# Changing a ceiling light and there seem to be wrong coloured wires

Tags: electrical, lighting, united-kingdom

I'm changing a ceiling light and am a bit confused (hence why I'm here!)
There are four cables coming out of the ceiling. Two cables with red/black/yellow&green wires, one cable with just red/black wires and one cable with only a red wire.
I've (successfully) changed lights on a loop system before, but it's the first time I've come across this...
Edit> Schoolboy error I'm afraid. No pics or notes taken of previous connection. My ever-so helpful wife disconnected them whilst I was washing the car (as prompt for me to get the new lights up)
Update: an earth wire has been cut short in the switch cable. And the single red wire must be from the extra wall switch I found!

I'm in the UK btw [image: image1]

Comment: did you take note of how the wires were connected?

Comment: Please include the pictures you took before disconnecting everything.  Impossible to tell anything from what you've shown.

Comment: Schoolboy error I'm afraid. No pics or notes taken of previous connection. My ever-so helpful wife disconnected them whilst I was washing the car (as prompt for me to get the new lights up)

Comment: Thankfully she switched off the power at the consumer unit first!

Comment: Start out by identifying the hot .feed, wires with a voltge detector. Then  check outlets and lights in other rooms to see if they still have power since one of those wires could be the source. Then remove  and pull out the switch that operated the old light and try to identify with wires go from there to the ceiling. Edit findings into your qusstion.

Comment: Are you in the UK by any chance? That looks like (pre-2004) UK wiring.  In that case I'd expect a cable from the consumer unit (maybe via other lights), a cable on to other lights (both of those with an earth connection), and a cable to a switch (with the earth cut short if the switch box and faceplate are plastic).  You appear to have a 4th cable, with just a red.  Is there another light controlled by the same switch? 2 switches controlling one light?

Comment: Cheers @ChrisH. Yes in UK. Sorry, should have said. Didn't realise this was US. Yes, the earth on the switch cable has been cut short. And I have found another light switch controlling this light. Would that mean, both of the switch wires go into the live connection on the light fitting?..

Comment: This isn't "US", however, there is probably a large majority of askers & answerers from the US here. That's why we ask for your locale - so those of us who _don't_ know other systems can keep quiet, and those who do can answer appropriately. ;)

Comment: @Chris it's international, but a lot of people assume US, so it's as well to be certain.  My suspicion is that the red&black and red only cables are for switching, but I can't find a diagram of exactly how it would be done with that combination.